# create binaty exeutable file from text file

Tags: linux

i using Linux with g cc compiler . i try to convert binary file into text file and  reverse it to executable binary file .when i try to run the reversed with ./filename file i get error : : bash: ./filename: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.need  help for this issue
here are the steps i made:

```
save hello.c file        // in main() only print "hello world"
gcc hello.c -o hello    //get executable file
xxd -b hello | cut -d" " -f 2-7 | tr "\n" " " > output.txt  // convert binary file to text file
sed -i 's/^\(.\)\{9\}//g' output.txt   
sed -i 's/\(.\)\{16\}$//g' output.txt
for i in $(cat output.txt) ; do printf "\x$i" ; done > reversebinfile //convert text file into binary file 
chmod 777 reversebinfile
./reversebinfile
get error : bash: ./shay: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of `xxd` is already a text file, why do you `cut` and `sed` it?

Also, `xxd -r` reverses the conversion:

```
xxd hello > output.txt
xxd -r output.txt > reversebinfile
```

Comment: @shay If this solves your problem, then consider marking it as *accepted*. You do that by clicking the "tick" next to the answer. Please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more, and of course read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in general.